# BST nodes are not saving when trying to create a preorder traversal of a previous tree in c

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, preorder, postorder

I am trying to see if tree A is the preorder traversal of tree B and to do so, I created two trees which during a transversal were supposed to save the values. However, after hours of debugging I found out that the trees values were ALWAYS 0. I am confused as to why the trees values are 0. I've done a multitude of print statements (some of which I've left in the code posted below) and I just cannot seem to pinpoint why this is happening. Can someone please nudge me in the correct direction? I thought maybe the function was deleting variables as it exited and in effort to get to the bottom of the issue I had the preorder function return the tree ( as seen below), however, the output is ALWAYS 0 for the tree.

Code:

```
typedef struct node
{
    // Each node holds a single integer.
    int data;

    // Pointers to the node's left and right children.
    struct node *left, *right;
} node;
int tree_diff(node *a, node *b)
{
    if (a == NULL && b == NULL)
        return 0;

    else if (a == NULL || b == NULL)
        return 1;


    else if (a->data != b->data)
        return 1;
    printf("A %d , B %d", a->data, b->data);

        return tree_diff(a->left, b->left) || tree_diff(a->right, b->right);
}

node *preorder_recursive(node *root, node *A)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return A;

    printf("root %d ", root->data);
    A = root;
    printf("= data %d\n", A->data);
    preorder_recursive(root->left, A->left);
    preorder_recursive(root->right, A->right);
}

void postorder_recursive(node *root, node *B)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return;
    B = root;
    postorder_recursive(root->left, B->left);
    postorder_recursive(root->right, B->right);
    printf("root %d ", root->data);
    printf("= data %d\n", B->data);
}

int kindredSpirits(node *a, node *b)
{

  // Get the preorder of a
  node *A = malloc(sizeof(node));
  A = preorder_recursive(a, A);

  // Get the postorder of b
  printf("\n\n");
  node *B = malloc(sizeof(node));
  postorder_recursive(b, B);

if(tree_diff(A,B) == 1)
  return 0;
else
  return 1;
}
```

The test case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "KindredSpirits.h"
  node *create_node(int data)
{
    node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));

    n->data = data;
    n->left = n->right = NULL;

    return n;
}

node *forest_fire(node *root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return NULL;

    forest_fire(root->left);
    forest_fire(root->right);
    free(root);
}

int main(void)
{
    node *root;

    root = create_node(23);
    root->left = create_node(12);
    root->left->left = create_node(5);
    root->left->right = create_node(18);
    root->right = create_node(71);
    root->right->right = create_node(56);

    printf("%s\n", !kindredSpirits(root, root) ? "Success!" : "fail whale :(");

    forest_fire(root);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you pass two parameters to `preorder_recursive` and `postorder_recursive`? I cannot follow your logic... It can be implemented as simple as `void preorder_recursive(node *root){ if (root != NULL) { printf("root %d ", root->data); preorder_recursive(root->left); preorder_recursive(root->right);} }`

Comment: @Arash I am trying to save the first tree's preorder transversal as the second tree in order to compare it with the other post order to see if the trees are identical. I thought that by sending two parameters, I could transverse through the two trees saving the first tree's values into the second trees and then after getting the preorder of one and the postorder of another I could then check to see if the two resulting trees were equal.

Comment: What is your end goal? You want to write a function to compare two trees?

Comment: @Arash I'm trying to write a function that figures out if tree a's preorder is equal to tree b's postorder without altering a or b. This is why I was triyng to save the transversal values to a different tree.

Comment: Your `preorder_recursive` returns a pointer but the bottom returns nothing. In both your recursive functions, you check `root` for `NULL`, but then, you do `A = root` and/or `B = root` (i.e. blowing away the values you need). If you do that, there is no need for a second arg in either function.

Comment: @starlight --  Creating another tree is not the way to compare postorder with preorder *traversals*. You can save the traversals into array of integers. During the preorder traversal, create an array of the data and compare it with the array that you get during the postorder traversal.

Comment: How about saving the traversed values to a linear stack/list. Use a separate one for each type of traversal. In the end, the resultant stack/lists should match

Comment: @Arash I started off with saving the transversals as strings, however, I could not figure out how to increment I correctly to save into a string. I'll take another look at that.

Comment: @CraigEstey I will look into that method as well.

Comment: @starlight Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code fragment that should get you started:

```
typedef struct node {
    // Each node holds a single integer.
    int data;

    // Pointers to the node's left and right children.
    struct node *left,
    struct node *right;
} node;

typedef struct list {
    int lst_max;                        // maximum number of allocated cells
    int lst_cur;                        // current number of filled cells
    int *lst_base;                      // traversal list
} list;

list list_a = { 0, 0, NULL };
list list_b = { 0, 0, NULL };

void
list_append(list *lst,int data)
{
    int newidx;

    newidx = lst->lst_cur;

    if (newidx >= lst->lst_max) {
        lst->lst_max += 100;
        lst->lst_base = realloc(lst->lst_base,sizeof(int) * lst->lst_max);
        if (lst->lst_base == NULL) {
            printf("list_append: malloc error\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    lst->lst_base[newidx] = data;

    lst->lst_cur = newidx + 1;
}

void
preorder_recursive(node *root,list *lst)
{

    if (root == NULL)
        return;

    list_append(lst,root->data);
    preorder_recursive(root->left,lst);
    preorder_recursive(root->right,lst);
}

void
postorder_recursive(node *root,list *lst)
{

    if (root == NULL)
        return;

    postorder_recursive(root->left,lst);
    postorder_recursive(root->right,lst);
    list_append(lst,root->data);
}

int
main(void)
{

    preorder_recursive(a,&list_a);
    postorder_recursive(b,&list_b);

    // compare list_a and list_b ...

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to write a function that figures out if tree a's preorder is equal to tree b's postorder without altering a or b.

I use arrays to save the traversals and then compare the value of the two arrays.

```
#define MAX_TREE_SIZE 100

void preorder_recursive(node *root, int* arr, int *len) {
  if (root != NULL){
    arr[(*len)++] = root->data;
    preorder_recursive(root->left, arr, len);
    preorder_recursive(root->right, arr, len);
  }
}

void postorder_recursive(node *root, int *arr, int *len) {
  if (root != NULL){
   postorder_recursive(root->left, arr, len);
   postorder_recursive(root->right, arr, len);
   arr[(*len)++] = root->data;
  }
}

int kindredSpirits(node *a, node *b){

 // Get the preorder of a
 int *arr1 = malloc(MAX_TREE_SIZE * sizeof(int));
 int len1 = 0;
 preorder_recursive(a, arr1, &len1);

 // Get the postorder of b
 int *arr2 = malloc(MAX_TREE_SIZE * sizeof(int));
 int len2 = 0;
 postorder_recursive(b, arr2, &len2);

 int ret = 0; // 2 traversals are equal
 if (len1 != len2) {
    ret = 1;
 } else {
   for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++){
     if (arr1[i] != arr2[i]){
       ret = 1;
       break;
     }
   }
 }

 free(arr1);
 free(arr2);
 return ret;
}
```